# Update Day of Month

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a select statement that is finding all the dates in the column that are on the 9th of the month, regardless of month and year:

```
SELECT *
FROM tblhosting
WHERE DAY( nextduedate ) =09
```

I would like to UPDATE the DAY to 10, but leave the month and year alone.

Any help?

Comment: Please include some code to show
[what you tried](http://whathaveyoutried.com)

Answer (score 4):

```
UPDATE tableName
SET nextduedate = DATE_ADD(nextduedate,INTERVAL 1 DAY) 
WHERE DAY(nextduedate) = 9
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/8ad90/1)

Source:

- [DATE_ADD](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-add)
- [DATE_ADD](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_date_add.asp)

Comment: Hi, I see you're new to SO. If you feel an answer solved the problem, please mark it as 'accepted' (*around 15mins to an hour later*)  by clicking the green check mark. This helps keep the focus on older SO which still don't have answers.